# Backslash works incorrectly in LIKE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I'd to use `LIKE` and backslash to search some names. The problem is Postgres understands backslash as escape character in `LIKE` clause. I tried to turn on `standard_conforming_strings` but it doesn't help.

```
SELECT h.software_id
    ,h.software_name
FROM software h
WHERE software_name LIKE '%\%';
```

This query doesn't show anything whereas I have a software name '\'.

I've heard someone mentioned `prepared statement`. I use Hibernate to do the above query.

```
     <persistence-unit name="policyPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MyApp</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

JPA

```
query.setParameter(1, "%" + searchCriteria.getSoftwareName() + "%");
```

But Postgres doesn't escape backslash properly.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike in regular string literals, the backslash does indeed act as an escape character, changing `standard_conforming_strings` doesn't change this.

In order to be able to search for a `%` or a `_` using `LIKE` you can the `escape` clause: `where x like '%#_' escape '#'` which defines the character `#` as the escape character for the like condition. Any character following the escape character will not be interpreted as a wildcard. So `like '%#_' escape '#'` searches for values that *end* with an underscore.

The backslash is the default escape character so not specifying the `escape` clause is the same as specifying `escape '\'`  (this behavior is defined by the SQL standard).

So you need to use:

```
select *
from stuff.foo
where software_name like '%\%' escape '#'
```

to prevent Postgres from using `\` as the escape character. The only other way is to escape the backslash using `'%\\%'` (note: only **two** backslashes here, not four as TimoSta suggested).

Here is the link to the Postgres manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: What's the meaning of ESCAPE '#'? Why is '#' here?

Comment: @Emerald214: as I wrote: that defines the escape character used in the like condition. It "disables" the processing of the backslash as the escape character. You could use any character that is unlikely to be part of your value string (or more precisely: any character that is unlikely to precede a SQL wildcard character)

Comment: A [reference to some documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3182) wouldn't go astray... :)

Comment: @NickGrealy: Thanks, good idea. I added a link to the Postgres manual. Your link is about HQL/JPQL which is something (completely?) different and follows different syntax rules. I wouldn't post that as a reference to a SQL question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - excellent, yeh I just threw up the first link I could find on it. Much better!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT h.software_id,
       h.software_name
FROM software h
WHERE software_name LIKE '%\\\\%';
```

The backslash is an escape prefix both for the LIKE clause of SQL and for strings in general, thus the double escaping.

Comment: Updated the question. Actually I'd like to pass only '\' into the query. The JPA or any libraries or snippet should do the rest (escaping things).

Comment: The backslash is **not** an escape character for "strings in general" (there is a setting in Postgres to turn on that non-standard and deprecated behavior, but it is highly recommended to not do that)